# SharePoint 2013 ribbon bar issues

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, administration, ribbon

We are experiencing an issue with SharePoint 2013.

When clicking on the ribbon bar in a page the tabs shows with broken images and buttons like (Save,checkout) is not working when click on it.

the issue occurs on a SharePoint 2013 on-prem production environment that we have setup.

[image]

any suggestions to solve the issue?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 sites are not responsive sites. Are you trying to access your site in ipad or any tablet devices?

Comment: Hi Dikesh, no i'm tried to browse it from desktop chrome and IE

Comment: ok, have you configured any custom master page or CSS in your site or this page, sometimes it create issues with SharePoint's OOTB functionalities

Comment: i have created custom master page and CSS but it cannot be the cause, because i have applied the same master page anf CSS on (DEV,QA,UAT) environments and its worked fine there.

Answer (score 0):

If you confirm that no custom master pages or CSS are configured in the site.

1.Use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see if there was an error during page loading.

2.Clear the browser cache and log back in.

3.If the problem persists, you can reset the pages to site definition in Site Settings or in SharePoint Designer.

When you reset a customized page to the site definition, you discard all changes to that page and revert it to how it was originally defined in the site definition.